# Audio output from Mitsubishi HC4000 to speakers doesn't work

Tags: audio, speakers

I don't manage to output the audio from my projector Mitsubishi HC4000 to my harman speakers, with a RCA to 3.5 jack adaptor.

[image]
[image]

I've connected the adaptor to the blue and red RCA output in the picture and to the speakers jack.
Also, I've connected an Apple TV to the projector with HDMI cable.

I've also tried to increase the speakers volume (very loud), but I can't even listen to the "soft" signal (I've checked this because I was afraid I needed an amplifier. Even without amplifier the audio signal should be slightly perceptible, but I can't really hear any difference).

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Mitsubishi HC4000 does not produce audio, the RCA jacks (red and blue) that you are using are for video signals only, not audio signals. These video projectors only take video in and project the images, they do not accept audio signals as far as I can tell. The intention is that you would take your audio source to a separate audio amplifier with speakers. Perhaps your computer can produce the audio while the video is being projected.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. One last question, for general knowledge: are the 3 RCA used simultaneously for video ? I mean, are there cable for video only with 3 RCAs ? I thought only 1 RCA was necessary for video. Thanks

Comment: This particular set of RCA connectors are called "component video" which means they break the video signal down to three parts but this is different than RGB. More detailed information is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_video

Comment: HDMI carries audio, so a video-only device could provide an audio output for connecting to speakers — my Dell U2410 monitor does so, for example — but indeed that does not appear to be a feature of *this* device.